Film about a woman who steals to get a Ferrari
Could anyone help me find this film, I saw it on tv probably late 80s early 90s
Its was about a girl who was obsessed about a fast car in a showroom I think the car was a Ferrari Dino.
She kept going to this showroom looking at the car, talking to the saleman saying she will come in and buy the car one day.
Anyway she wanted this car that much she did whatever it took to get the money to buy it, stealing,buying and selling cars, even stealing them back so she could re sell the car.
In the end the police were on her case, and at the end of the film she does get the money together, goes and buys the car from the showroom, drives it for a few miles then sets fire to it as she knows it going to all end for her.
What is this Film Please? 

Sounds like Sweet Revenge from 1976 with Stockard Channing and Sam Waterston.

Vurrla, also known as Dandy, is a car thief. As a public defender tries in vain to understand her, the only thing driving the young woman is to steal enough automobiles to make enough money to buy her dream car, a Ferrari Dino.

Here are a few minutes from the film:



